# Got confused about define with dependencies in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, commonjs

I know in RequireJS, we can use define() to define a module with dependencies.

The things I got confused is such chunk code in jQuery.

```
// ready.js
define([
  "../core",
  "../core/init",
  "../deferred"
], function( jQuery ) {
   // ...
})
```

Actually I can not figure out the dependencies with `"../core"` and `"../core/init"`,
as RequireJS says,

> > RequireJS also assumes by default that all dependencies are scripts, so it does not expect to see a trailing ".js" suffix on module IDs.

But there isn't a file called `../core.js`, just a `../core` directory.
So is `../core` dependency needless?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you don't have to specify folders as dependencies, only scripts that you want to load.

```
// ready.js
define([
  "../core/init",
  "../deferred"
], function(init, deferred) {
   // ...
});
```

And to say more, RequireJS does not even allow you to mark the entire folder as a dependency.